# The Ducci Sequence

Tags: programming-challenge, rust

I wrote the following Rust code to solve [this task on /r/DailyProgrammer](https://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer/comments/8sjcl0/20180620_challenge_364_intermediate_the_ducci/).

> Given an n-tuple of numbers as input, the Ducci Sequence is formed by
>   taking the absolute difference of the difference between neighboring
>   elements. (The last result is the difference between the first and
>   last elements.)
>
> ### Example input
>
> ```
> [0; 653; 1854; 4063]
> ```
>
> ### Example output
>
> Emit the number of steps taken to get to either an all 0 tuple or when
>   it enters a stable repeating pattern.
>
> ```
> [0; 653; 1854; 4063]
> [653; 1201; 2209; 4063]
> [548; 1008; 1854; 3410]
> [460; 846; 1556; 2862]
> [386; 710; 1306; 2402]
> [324; 596; 1096; 2016]
> [272; 500; 920; 1692]
> [228; 420; 772; 1420]
> [192; 352; 648; 1192]
> [160; 296; 544; 1000]
> [136; 248; 456; 840]
> [112; 208; 384; 704]
> [96; 176; 320; 592]
> [80; 144; 272; 496]
> [64; 128; 224; 416]
> [64; 96; 192; 352]
> [32; 96; 160; 288]
> [64; 64; 128; 256]
> [0; 64; 128; 192]
> [64; 64; 64; 192]
> [0; 0; 128; 128]
> [0; 128; 0; 128]
> [128; 128; 128; 128]
> [0; 0; 0; 0]
> 24 steps
> ```

I'm aware all the extra functions and error handling are a bit exaggerated for a task this easy, but I'm learning rust at the moment so I tried to get things right.

```
extern crate regex;

use std::io::Write;
use std::fmt::Display;
use std::fmt;
use regex::Regex;
use std::io;
use std::error;


fn main() {
    match read_input() {
        Ok(tuple) => {
            run(tuple);
        }   
        Err(e) => {
            eprintln!("An error occured: {}", e);
        }
    }
}

/// Tries to read input from standard input
fn read_input() -> Result<Tuple, Error> {
    print!("input: ");
    io::stdout().flush().unwrap();

    let mut input = String::new();
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut input)?;

    Tuple::new(input)
}

/// runs Ducci sequence calculation and prints every step
fn run(tuple: Tuple) {
    let mut i = tuple;

    let mut history: Vec<Tuple> = Vec::new();
    let mut steps = 1;

    while !&i.zeros() && !history.contains(&i) {
        let next = i.next();
        history.push(i);
        i = next;
        println!("{}", i);
        steps += 1;
    }

    println!("{} steps", steps);
}

struct Tuple {
    data: Vec<i32>,
}

impl Tuple {
    fn new(line: String) -> Result<Tuple, Error> {
        // Regex for allowed inputs: (a, b, c, ..., d)
        let re = Regex::new(r"\(((\d)+, )*(\d)+\)").unwrap();

        if!re.is_match(line.as_str()) {
            Err(Error::ParsingError) 
        }
        else {
            // seperate single numbers, parse to integer and push into tuple instance
            let sep = Regex::new(r"(, |\(|\))").unwrap();
            let mut data: Vec<i32> =  Vec::new();
            for numbers in sep.split(line.as_str()) {
                match numbers.parse::<i32>() {
                    Ok(number) => {
                        data.push(number);
                    },
                    // ignore newline and empty captures
                    Err(_) => {},
                }   
            }
            Ok(Tuple {
                data: data,
            })
        }   
    }

    /// Calculates and returns next tuple in ducci sequence
    fn next(&self) -> Tuple {
        let mut data: Vec<i32> = Vec::new();

        // calculate first n - 1 new values
        for i in 0..self.dimension() - 1 {
            data.push((self.data[i] - self.data[i + 1]).abs());
        }
        // calculate last value
        data.push((self.data[self.dimension() - 1] - self.data[0]).abs());

        Tuple {
            data: data,
        }
    }

    /// Returns tuples dimension
    fn dimension(&self) -> usize {
        self.data.len()
    }

    /// Determines whether tuple only contains zeros
    fn zeros(&self) -> bool {
        self.data.iter().fold(true, |acc, x| {acc && *x == 0})
    }
}

impl PartialEq for Tuple {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Tuple) -> bool {
        if self.dimension() != other.dimension() { 
            false 
        }
        else {
            let mut e = true;
            for i in 0..self.dimension() {
                e = e && self.data[i] == other.data[i];
            }
            e
        } 
    }
}

impl Display for Tuple {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        let mut s = String::new();

        s.push_str("[");

        for i in 0..self.dimension() - 1 {
            s.push_str(self.data[i].to_string().as_str());
            s.push_str("; ");
        }
        s.push_str(self.data[self.dimension() - 1].to_string().as_str());
        s.push_str("]");

        write!(f, "{}", s)
    }
}






#[derive(Debug)]
enum Error {
    ReadingError,
    ParsingError,
}

impl Display for Error {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> Result<(), fmt::Error> {
        match self {
            Error::ReadingError => {
                f.write_str("Error while reading input line from standard input.")

            }
            Error::ParsingError => {
                f.write_str("Input line does not meet format requirements: (a, b, c, ..., d)")
            }
        }
    }
}

impl error::Error for Error {}

impl std::convert::From<std::io::Error> for Error {
    fn from(_e: std::io::Error) -> Self {
        Error::ReadingError
    }
}
```

What are youre thoughts? What can I do better or in a more elegant way?

Answer (score 5):

This is only a summary of some remarks that came to mind when I read your code. It looks good, but I would run it through `rustfmt`. Also, your delimiters are parentheses and commas (`(…,…)`) instead of brackets and semicolons (`[…;…]`), that seems off.

## Use `return` to short-circuit were appropriate

While you can use expressions instead of explicit `return`s, an explicit `return` can make a function simpler in some circumstances. For example, your `eq` implementation can get simplified:

```
impl PartialEq for Tuple {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Tuple) -> bool {
        if self.dimension() != other.dimension() {
            false
        } else {
            for i in 0..self.dimension() {
                if self.data[i] != other.data[i] {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            true
        }
    }
}
```

We don't have any mutable state `e`. Furthermore, if the first element differs, we don't need to check all elements.

## Use `derive` where appropriate

However, your `PartialEq` implementation acts the same as the `Vec<i32>` one. It's therefore appropriate to use

```
#[derive(PartialEq, Debug)]
struct Tuple {
    …
}
```

instead. No need to reinvent the wheel here.

## Follow existing interfaces

Your `fn new(input: String) -> Result<…,…>` looks almost like `from_str`. We should use `from_str` from `FromStr` instead:

```
impl FromStr for Tuple {
    type Err = Error;

    fn from_str(line: &str) -> Result<Self, Self::Err> {
        // Regex for allowed inputs: (a, b, c, ..., d)
        let re = Regex::new(r"\(((\d)+, )*(\d)+\)").unwrap();

        if!re.is_match(line) {
            Err(Error::ParsingError) 
        }
        else {
            // seperate single numbers, parse to integer and push into tuple instance
            let sep = Regex::new(r"(, |\(|\))").unwrap();
            let mut data: Vec<i32> =  Vec::new();
            for numbers in sep.split(line) {
                match numbers.parse::<i32>() {
                    Ok(number) => {
                        data.push(number);
                    },
                    // ignore newline and empty captures
                    Err(_) => {},
                }   
            }
            Ok(Tuple {
                data: data,
            })
        }   
    }
}
```

## Prefer non-owning types when possible

As you can see, `from_str` uses `&str` instead of `String`. `from_str` doesn't need to take ownership of the string, and neither did your original `new`. Indeed, all your uses of `line` in `new` needed `as_str()`.

## Use specialized functions where appropriate

`zeroes` uses `fold` with a boolean state. This has the same problem as your `eq` implementation: if the first number differs from zero, we will still check *all* numbers.

Instead, use [`all`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.all):

```
fn zeros(&self) -> bool {
    self.data.iter().all(|x| *x == 0)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Regarding my delimiters I wasn't sure what to use, because both versions are present in the task.

Comment: About derives, the `fn new(line: String) -> Result<Tuple, Error>` should be an implementation of `FromStr`

Answer (score 4):

Not a review, but an extended comment.

The loop detection by means of `history` drives the time complexity quadratic to the number of steps. There are two ways out: either

- use a Floyd loop detection (with `slow` and `fast` tuples), or
- exploit the property of Ducci sequence: it becomes periodic once it reaches the "binary" form, that is all non-zero elements are equal.

This way you don't need `history` at all. Space complexity is \$O(1)\$, and time complexity is linear to the number of steps.